# Is there a setting in SQL Server to always recompile views on each run?

Tags: sql-server, view, precompiled

Having once again been bitten by SQL Server not updating all views properly when you add a field to an underlying table (whaaaaaat!), I am wondering if there is a setting in SQL Server that forces it to recompile the view on every use. Then I could switch this on while doing updates and then when done switch it off again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no automated way that I know off

Take a look at [how to make sure that the view will have the underlying table changes by using sp_refreshview](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-make-sure-that-the-view-will-have)

What you can do is create the view with `SCHEMABINDING`, that way nobody can modify the tables without dropping the view first.